# Rearranging seats randomly, mean number of pairs swapping places?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have 11 people sitting on 11 chairs. They then get up and rearrange themselves. I need to calculate the expected value/mean of the pairs who swapped places.

I haven't really got a good grasp on how to even approach this problem... counting the possible states seems far too complex.

Comment: If A goes to B to C to A, how many pairs is that?

Comment: no pairs. we're looking only for cases in which, in one arrangement A and B are sitting on chairs 1 and 5 respectively, and in the other, A and B are sitting on chairs 5 and 1 respectively.

Comment: If I count this as two pairs, then the problem would be much more interesting (but I will not go further here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I preassume that a "swap" concerns only two persons and for persons A and B only takes place iff after rearrangement A and B have switched places.

**Guide**:

There are $\binom{11}2=55$ pairs.

Number them and let $X_i$ take value $1$ if pair $i$ swapped places and $0$ otherwise.

Then $X:=\sum_{i=1}^{55}X_i$ equals the number or pairs that swapped places.

Now find $\mathbb EX$ by using linearity of expectations and symmetry.

Comment: The question is ambiguous, as I pointed out in the comment. A 3-cycle could be counted as 2 or 0 swaps.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  I added a preassumption.

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate Xi. It also seems as though these aren't all uncorrelated - in AB, CD, EF, GH and IJ all swapped, then naturally no pair involving K can swap?

Comment: Linearity of expectation does not require that the rv's are uncorrelated. Further $\mathbb EX_1=P(X_1=1)$ because $X_1$ has Bernoulli distribution.